# Why does RMI registry need access to stub class file?

Tags: java, rmi, stub

As far as my understanding goes RMI registry maintains a HashMap sort of data structure that stores name and stub mapping where stub is essentially an Object - Atleast that what we get when we call `Naming.lookup()`.

When I start remiregistry from the directory that has stub class file everything works fine. Binding happens correctly. But If I don't and I startup remote service -

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try {
        GreeterService greeterService = new GreeterServiceImpl();
        Naming.rebind("greeterServiceObj", greeterService);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get Exception -

```
C:\Users\athakur\newJavaWorkspace\RMIDemo\src>java GreeterServiceImpl
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception
is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception i
s:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GreeterServiceImpl_Stub
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:400)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java
:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:
649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.j
ava:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:
908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at GreeterServiceImpl.main(GreeterServiceImpl.java:19)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exceptio
n is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GreeterServiceImpl_Stub
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:390)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java
```

1. Why does rmiregistry need stub class file?
2. What is that unmarshalling error that I see? Even if rmiregistry is not able to unmarshall the stub exported by UnicastRemoteObject to it shouldn't rmiregistry log that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does rmiregistry need stub class file?

Because it's just another RMI server and obeys the same semantics as other RMI servers and clients.

> What is that unmarshalling error that I see?

It is exactly the same exception that any other RMI client would get if it passed a parameter to a server that didn't have that class available to it.

> Even if rmiregistry is not able to unmarshall the stub exported by UnicastRemoteObject to it shouldn't rmiregistry log that error?

No, because the RMI Registry doesn't even get to see it. It all happens within the RMI runtime while ummarshalling the call, before the Registry code even executes. In fact the Registry code hasn't executed at all.

Comment: So RMI registry throws this exception back to the remote service that is trying to bind?

Comment: Well, the RMI runtime in the registry JVM does that.

Comment: Does same happen with `JNDI`? If I try create oracle JDBC data source and register it in rmiregistry , binding will fail if rmi registry does not have drivers jar file accessible?

Comment: See [DataSource](http://pag-www.gtisc.gatech.edu/conchord/examples/jdk/sun/jdbc/odbc/ee/DataSource.java.html) source code. It extend `CommonDataSource` which implements `Serializable `. But that's not the point.  lets say some resource is serializable and I want to bind it. Does the corresponding resource class files need to be accessible to RMI registry and is the behavior same for RMI and JNDI?

Comment: It applies to the RMI Registry and any other RMI server or client, as I already said, however you access it. Ultimately it has to be an RMI call, and those are the semantics.